# How can I extract text from a string using regex or substring?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms, substring

What I'm doing now is this:

```
if (textforspeech.contains("upload completed"))
                                {
                                    String varr = textforspeech.substring(17,3);
                                    String varr1 = textforspeech.substring(0, 16);
                                    String varr2 = textforspeech.substring(21);
```

But my program crash on the first substring 17,3

The text in the `textforspeech` is: "upload completed 100 0"
The number 100 present percentages and will be all the time 100.
And the number 0 present seconds it can be changed sometimes 0 sometimes 1 and sometimes 34.5

In `varr` I need to put the 100 as string "100"
In `varr1` "upload completed"
in `varr2` "0"

Only `varr2` might be change in the next times could be "1" or "45.5" 
Before I added the seconds to the string `textforspeech` it was only:

"upload completed 100" so I could make `substring(17)` and `substring(0,16)`
But now I added the seconds after the 100 so how can extract it all to the three vars ?

Comment: Use `.LastIndexOf(' ')+1`  to get the last number. The 2 former values are known, why extract them? Just assign: `String varr = "100"; String varr1 = "upload completed";`. And why do you assign the variables inside `if`?

Comment: It is Contains instead of contains and Substring instead of substring. Method names start with an uppercase.

Comment: Oops sorry it's java not c#. I will make new question. What to do with this one ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
string[] parts = textforspeech.split(new char[] { ' ' });

string varr = parts[2]; // "100"
string varr1 = string.format("{0} {1}", parts[0], parts[1]);  // "upload completed"
string varr2 = parts[3]; // value
```